# Finding the vectors/modes "maximally responsible" for the fluctutation of a quantity?

Tags: time-series, correlation, eigenvalues, cross-correlation, canonical-correlation

I have a question which I fear might be simple but i am completely unable to figure out.

Lets say we have a time-series of a vector of coordinates which define a molecule ( column vector of x,y,z) coordinates. This is just a simple trajectory. This trajectory also has a time-series of another quantity eg. energy.

Both the coordinates and the energy fluctuate with time.

I want to find out the vectors( which might be  linear combination of the coordinates) which are maximally responsible for this fluctuation.

I feel this is a kind of eigenvalue problem, but I cant to seem to figure it out. While a PCA/SVD of just the time-series coordinates can tell me which directions are active the most, how do I relate the correlation of energy fluctuation ?

*Edit:
By "maximally responsible" I mean the fluctuation in the value of  direction along time(*which might be a linear combination of the coordiantes*) would have the best overlap with the fluctuation of the energy quantity. So

1. there should be something which measures/quantifies how much two time-series are similar/correlated to each other.
2. There should be a way to compute which linear combination of the input-basis correlates best which the energy fluctuation.

I apologize for lack of correct maths nomenclature which is due to lack of my knowledge.

Comment: Please explain what "responsible for" means to you and how you would quantify it.

Comment: Edit: By "maximally responsible" I mean the fluctuation of this direction along time(which might be a linear combination of the coordinates) would have the best overlap with the fluctuation of the energy quantity. So
1.  there should be something which measures/quantifies how much two time-series are similar/correlated to each other.

2. There should be a way to compute which linear combination of the input-basis correlates best which the energy fluctuation.

I apologize for lack of correct maths nomenclature which is due to lack of my knowledge.

Comment: To clarify, I am talking about the overlap between two time-series. So the energy fluctuates with time. And so do the values each of the cartesian coordinates. The fluctuation of certain corrdinates should correlate best with the energy fluctuation. I am asking if from a "mathematical" analysis, its possible to build these coordinates,  which might be something obvious like a bond-length. But, what I wish is for this  thing to automatically come out from some this mathematical analysis.

Comment: They are Cartesian coordinates(x,y,z positions) of the atoms from a molecular dynamics trajectory. There is no external field.

Comment: These atoms are in gas-phase. So they just interact with each other. There is no heat-bath/solvent. There is no special software I used. It just force-evaluation and through electronic structure computation and propagation  in time through velocity-verlet.

Comment: I see. You have a microcanonical simulation of a mixture of atoms in the gas phase w/electrostatic, multi-polar interactions. No covalent bonds, so no actual molecules. My reference to Brooks-Karplus normal mode analysis of molecular dynamics of a molecule is far away from what you actually looking for. Modes of oscillation will be limited by the time scale of your simulation. Unless you linearize and solve the equations of motion, all you have are observations of high frequency modes. I'd take a characteristic length (diameter of atomic cluster?) & cross correlate w/ pot. energy.